# Synchronize directories with Gradle

Tags: gradle

How can I synchronize two directories after task execution? I can do it like this:

```
task syncDirs(type: Sync) {
    ...
}

task someTask {
    doLast {
        syncDirs.execute()
    }
}
```

But method "execute" is internal and I have to avoid it.
Thanks for the answer in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs, you can use `syncDirs.dependsOn(someTask)`, or call the `delete` and `copy` *methods* inside `someTask.doLast` (that's how `Sync` is currently implemented).

Comment: I want to consider executing of "someTask" and synchronization as a single action, so I use "copy" and "ant.delete" methods in "doLast" indeed. But I think since the "Project" has method "copy", that is similar to the task "Copy", it would be nice to have method "sync", that is similar to the task "Sync". In any case thank you for the answer.

Comment: You can use Gradle's `delete` instead of `ant.delete`.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know Gradle's "delete" doesn't allow to use wildcards (for example, `include: "**/*.java"`).

Answer (score 1):

```
task myTask << {

    copy {
        from 'src_dir'
        into 'dst_dir'
        include 'myfile.txt'
    }

    sync {
        from "src_dir/foo"
        into "dst_dir/bar"
    }
}
```

In Gradle 1.10, you can do things like copy files and sync dirs all in a single task.  I prefer this to having separate tasks for copying and syncing.

For syncing, the idea of doing a separate delete and copy, as suggested above, seems tedious.  I'm glad I can call `sync` to do both.

Comment: Yes, I found method `sync` when I was going to write my own plugin for this task. :) In any case thank you for the answer.

Comment: sync blocks inside of other tasks appear to have broken or been removed in 2.0. Have you experienced that as well?